# Error while changing the AccountId for a Contact

Tags: contact

Since a few days we're getting the below error while trying to change the Account Id for a Contact for all user roles:

> Error:User doesn't have the access to create or edit account contact relationship

Any suggestions on how to fix/debug this?

Comment: Stupid question, but do they have access to it?

Comment: It's definitely worth investigating at Profile level what CRUD access users have to Accounts and Contacts.

Comment: @NickCook Yes, they have access and can create/edit to both Account and Contact. The only problem is with the Account Id on the Contact.

Comment: What's the Org-Wide Defaults on those related objects?

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard salesforce error that I recognize - do you have a Validation Rule on Contact that can return that error, or a Trigger on Contact that could be returning that error?

Answer (score 0):

As Jason Clark suggested, there was a Validation Rule added by a developer - with custom error message - that was not working as expected. The VR was added to AccountContactRelation sObject, of which I was not aware until now.